# Using Service Controller in Classic ASP

Tags: .net, vbscript, asp-classic, servicecontroller

I'm currently trying to see if I can use `ServiceController` in my Classic ASP page so that the page can send custom commands to my Windows Service. All the articles and questions I have read online were about using ASP.NET or another application/component (but sadly I'm limited to only using Classic ASP). Both of my attempts failed because I get this error:

`Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401' Expected end of statement`

Here are my two attempts at trying to use `ServiceController` on my asp page:

Attempt #1 Expected end of statement points to '('

```
Dim myService
Set myService = New ServiceController("MyNewService")
myService.ExecuteCommand(0)
myService.ExecuteCommand(1)
myService.ExecuteCommand(2)
```

Attempt #2 Expected end of statement points to 'As'

```
Dim myService As New ServiceController("MyNewService")
myService.ExecuteCommand(0)
myService.ExecuteCommand(1)
myService.ExecuteCommand(2)
```

So, is it possible to use ServiceController in Classic ASP? Please explain how it is possible or why it is not possible.

Comment: Are you sure the `ServiceController` is being recognized at all? Did you include the `Class` definition?

Comment: `VBScript` does not support constructors with parameters. Did you try `Set myService = New ServiceController`?

Comment: @haim770 Yeah, the `ServiceController` class was not defined, but Alex's answer explains why. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295049/criteria-for-flagging-an-off-topic-question

Comment: He's asking for either 1) links or 2) do my work for me.  Both of which are VERY MUCH off topic.  Again, go to meta. Discuss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ServiceController` is a .Net class, VBScript has no idea what it is.

Given that its also not exposed via COM it cannot be used from within VBScript.

Create a .Net COM Visible assembly that wraps the calls to a `ServiceController`,  instantiate it in VBScript (`Server.CreateObject()`) and call methods you have implemented in C#/VB.Net that do what you need.